# A problem about the supremum of countable stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $\left(\Omega\ ,\mathcal{F}\ ,\mathbb{P} \right)$  be a probability space with a countable filtration $F=\left\{ \mathcal{F}_0,\mathcal{F}_1,\cdots,\mathcal{F}_n,\cdots \right\}$.
$\left\{ T_n \right\}$ is a sequence (countable infinite) of stopping times.

Let $S_1=\wedge_n{T_n}$ and $S_2=\vee_n{T_n}$ , it is easy to show that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are also stopping times and that $\mathcal{F}_{S_1} = \bigcap_{n}{\mathcal{F}_{T_n}}$ .

It is also easy to show that $\mathcal{F}_{T_1\vee T_2}=\mathcal{F}_{T_1}\vee\mathcal{F}_{T_2}=\sigma\left(\mathcal{F}_{T_1}\cup\mathcal{F}_{T_2}\right)$ , but I wonder whether $$\mathcal{F}_{S_2} = \vee_{n}{\mathcal{F}_{T_n}}$$  still holds.

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2478216/36150

Comment: ... and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3307425/36150)

Comment: ... and also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3529959/36150)

Comment: Hi @saz, what does $\mathcal{F}_{T_1}\vee\mathcal{F}_{T_2}$ mean?

Comment: @Navier_Stokes $\mathcal{F}_{T_1} \vee \mathcal{F}_{T_2}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\mathcal{F}_{T_1}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{T_2}$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_{T_1} \vee \mathcal{F}_{T_2} = \sigma(\mathcal{F}_{T_1},\mathcal{F}_{T_2})$.

Comment: @saz you meant $\mathcal{F}_{T_1}\vee\mathcal{F}_{T_2}:=\sigma\left(\mathcal{F}_{T_1}\cup\mathcal{F}_{T_2}\right)$?

Comment: @Navier_Stokes Well, it's just a matter of notation... if you prefer to write it like this, then go ahead (for me both things are (by definition) the same).