# $\sigma$-field of an increasing sequence of stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stopping-times

Let us consider the sequence $(\tau_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of stopping times that takes values in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\tau_n \uparrow \tau$, and $\tau < \infty$. Prove the following equality:

### $\mathcal{F}_\tau=\sigma(\cup_n \mathcal{F_{\tau_n}})$

I'm having problem with both the inclusions, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you assume that the underlying filtration is right-continuous...?

Comment: @saz do you mean for the family of filtrations $(\mathcal{F_t})_{t \geq 0}$? In that case no.

Comment: **Suggestion:** Because the stopping times are integer valued, the convergence $\tau_n\uparrow\tau$ means that for each $k\in\Bbb N$ you have $\{\tau=k\}=\cup_n\{\tau_n=k\}$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Why should this be true? $\tau_n(\omega)=k$ for some $n$ does not imply $\tau(\omega)=k$. I guess you mean $$\{\tau=k\} = \bigcup_n \bigcap_{j \geq n} \{\tau_j = k\}.$$

Comment: @saz: Yes indeed, $\{\tau=k\}=\cup_n\cap_{j\ge n}\{\tau_j=k\}$. And also (for what it is worth) $\{\tau=k\}=\cap_n\cup_{j\ge n}\{\tau_j=k\}$, so that even $\{\tau=k\}=\lim_n\{\tau_n=k\}$.

Comment: Related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3307425/36150)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Let $S,T$ be two stopping times (with respect to a common filtration). Show: If $S \leq T$, then $\mathcal{F}_S \subseteq \mathcal{F}_T$.
2. Conclude that $$\sigma \left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_{\tau_n} \right) \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\tau}.$$
3. Prove that $\{\tau_n = \tau\} \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
4. Show that for any $F \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $F \cap \{\tau_n=\tau\} \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau_n}$.
5. Conclude that $$F = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (F \cap \{\tau=\tau_n\}) \in \sigma \left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_{\tau_n} \right) $$ for any $F \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$.

Comment: $\sup_n \tau_n = \tau,$ in your approach you didn't need to use $\tau<\infty,$ right?

Comment: @Kurt.W.Actually I think I did. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3529959/36150) for the more general case.