# In the proof of the Optional Sampling Theorem for a Uniformly Integrable Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I wish to prove that for stopping times $S \leq T$ and $X_n$ a uniformly integrable martingale, $E(X_T | \mathcal{F}_S) = X_S$.  I am well aware this is a standard result, but part of the proof I have been trying to learn confuses me.  It goes as follows:

$X_n$ being UI implies $X_n \rightarrow X \quad a.s.$ and in $L^1$ for some $X \in L^1$(martingale convergence)

We define $Y_n \equiv X_{S \wedge n}$.  Clearly $Y_n$ is a UI martingale with respect to the filtration $\{\mathcal{G_n}\} = \{\mathcal{F}_{S\wedge n}\}$ as:

(1) $E(X_{S \wedge n} | \mathcal{G}_m) = E(X_{S \wedge n} | \mathcal{F}_{S \wedge m}) = X_{S \wedge m}$ for $m \leq n$ by bounded stopping times, and

(2) $X_{S \wedge n} = E(X_{n}|\mathcal{F}_{S \wedge n}) = E(E(X|\mathcal{F}_n)|\mathcal{F}_{S \wedge n}) = E(X | \mathcal{F}_{S \wedge n})$ again by martingale convergence, the properties of bounded stopping times and the tower property.

The same argument can be made for $Y_n \equiv X_{T \wedge n}$, so $X_{T \wedge n} \rightarrow X_T \quad a.s.$ and in $L^1$.

We now apply the above arguments to $Y_{S \wedge n}$:

(**) $E(X_T | \mathcal{F}_{S \wedge n}) = Y_{S \wedge n} = X_{T \wedge S \wedge n} = X_{S \wedge n}$ (as $S \leq T$)

Taking limits and invoking Levy's theorem, we obtain that

$X_S = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(X_T|\mathcal{F}_{S \wedge n}) = E(X_T|\sigma(\cup_{n=0}^\infty \mathcal{F}_{S \wedge n}))$

It is somehow supposed to be "obvious" $\sigma(\cup_{n=0}^\infty \mathcal{F}_{S \wedge n})) = \mathcal{F}_S$.  I don't see this AT ALL.

It is indeed obvious that since $\mathcal{F}_{S \wedge n} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_S$, $\sigma(\cup_{n=0}^\infty \mathcal{F}_{S \wedge n})) \subseteq \mathcal{F}_S$.  The other direction is not clear to me, and I tried addressing in this post: [Stopping Times and Filtrations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529959/stopping-times-and-filtrations/3529991#3529991) to no avail.  Please help me clarify the end of this proof.  It is driving me insane.

Comment: I promise to have a look at the answer in the other post.

Comment: Do you assume that $S$ is a finite stopping time (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(S<\infty)=1$)? If so, take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2478216/36150)

Comment: I gave a counterexample in the other post : it seems that further conditions on $S$ have to be present and utilized.

Comment: So then this proof  is incorrect?  Whenever I look at anyone's notes, this is the version that is presented, and the conclusion is simply stated after the (**) line in my proof.  And if it's wrong, I fail to see where it falters, because every line up to the last is rigorously justified as far as I can tell