# For any stopping time $\rho$, $\mathscr{F}_\rho$ is generated by $\cup_i \mathscr{F}_{\rho \wedge i}$

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $\rho$ be a $\mathscr{F}_t$ stopping time. Then how do we show that $\mathscr{F}_\rho = \sigma(\cup_i (\mathscr{F}_\rho \cap \mathscr{F}_i))$?

I can show this if $\rho$ is a bounded stopping time, since each $A \in \mathscr{F}_\rho$ is $\cup_i (A \cap \{\rho \le i\})$, and $A \cap \{\rho \le i\} \in \mathscr{F}_\rho \cap \mathscr{F}_i$.

However, if $\{\rho = \infty\} \neq \emptyset$, then I am stuck. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Noting that $\mathcal{F}_{\varrho} \cap \mathcal{F}_i = \mathcal{F}_{\varrho \wedge i}$, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3529959/36150) (the proof is somewhat easier if $\varrho$ is a **finite** stopping time, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2478216/36150)).